# C# EF Core how to initialize list for a Model only once?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'd want to fill Item's List with some default Items

```
public class Data
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; protected set; }

    public List<Item> Items { get; set; } = new List<Item>(4) { new Item(), new Item(), new Item(), new Item() };

    public DateTime CreationDate { get; protected set; }

    public Question()
    {
        CreationDate = DateTime.Now;
    }   
}

public class Item
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; protected set; }
    public string Text { get; set; } = "";
}
```

I have two methods in my Controller:

```
public ActionResult add(Data data)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _db.Data.Add(data);
        _db.SaveChanges();
    }
    return RedirectToAction("getData", new { id = data.Id });
}

public ViewResult getData(string id)
{
    var _id = Convert.ToInt32(id);

    // Data object is already added to the database with 4 elements
    var pre = _db.Data.Find(_id).Items.Count(); // Count's 4 with correct data

    var el = _db.Data
            .Include(q => q.Items)
            .Where(x => x.Id == _id)
            .FirstOrDefault();

    var post = _db.Data.Find(_id).Items.Count(); // count's 8 

    return View(el);
}
```

But when I execute getData,

```
// Data object is already added to the database with 4 real(manually added) Items elements
var pre = _db.Data.Find(_id).Items.Count(); // Count's 4 with correct data

var el = _db.Data
        .Include(q => q.Items)
        .Where(x => x.Id == _id)
        .FirstOrDefault();

var post = _db.Data.Find(_id).Items.Count(); // count's 8
```

then this happens:
My list has 8 elements in it and 4 of them are "real, manually added via form" and 4 are default, meanwhile before that

> var el = _db.Data.Include(q => q.Items).Where(x => x.Id == _id).FirstOrDefault();

It has only 4 "real, manually added elements"

When I execute this code again, then it still stays at 8 elements - it does not increase by 4.

Additionally, if my list is changing because of those "default" values, then why `CreationTime` does not?

There's no difference when I initialize those values via

> new List(4) { new Item(), new Item(), new Item(), new Item() };

or

> Items.Add(new Item()); in ctor.

Comment: Can you try AsNoTracking() after Where clause and then check ?

Comment: @viveknuna Well, now 2nd Count() check (var post =....) returns value 4 which is correct, but later then whem I'm doing return other_method(el), and it again has 8 elements.

Comment: Try removing Include then

Comment: @viveknuna I removed include and then my real data (Items) is not even shown in debugger, it's just empty (default) ``Item`` list. Include is required in EF Core when it comes to relations (afaik)

Comment: Edit in previous comment: ``it's just (default) Item list with 4 default elements (those from new List<Item>(4){4x new}`` (...)